# Opacity для фона

Tags: html, css

Есть код:

```css
.background {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="test2">
    <div class="test3">
      <div class='background'>
        <span class="test4">lorumsukaipsum</span><span class="test5">ipsumblya</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как можно установить `opacity: 0.1` у класса `background` при этом не меняя прозрачность текста?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Comment: Для красного background: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);

Comment: @aloe, если этот ответ вам помог, отметьте его как правильный

Comment: @Yuri Не мог этого сделать пару минут назад, но сейчас все ок!